# Java - getActionCommand() encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, actionevent

Good afternoon,
I am having a problem with a "ActionEvent" in method "getActionCommand()" when there are special characters ex .: (ã) is generating encoding problems.
I wonder if there is a way to determine the character encoding of getActionCommand () method?

ex:
this expression

Rec Div Ativ Ñ Tribut

it is shown

Rec DÃ­v Ativ Ã± Tribut

-- Edit

What I am doing is a "self-Complete" using a popup menu, which to start typing it suggests a general ledger account that has informed description, by clicking on a popup option he seeks in a map  the id of the ledger account, based on the name, as have some accounts with names with special characters it is not finding the code to add, to perform debug realized that the special characters were in trouble in the encoding

google did not help me much ... :(

sorry about my English...

Comment: It's unclear why you print the action command and why it contains these characters in the first place, but if you post no code, don't say what you're trying to achieve, don't say what you expect to happen and don't say what happens instead, you won't get useful answers.

Comment: Sorry, as I have to use a translator tried to avoid dwell too.

Comment: What is shown is UTF-8 bytes taken as single byte encoding. If that is shown in a browser look what the encoding says.